# How to properly calculate sums in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, haskell

Fairly new Haskell user here, I'm trying to find the sum of integers 1 to n using threads. I'm aware there are formulas to do this, but I want to play around with threads so I'm more comfortable with optimizing. I'm using GHC version 8.6.5 to compile with `-O2` and, for the parallel one, `-threaded`.

Single-core code:

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Running: "
  let n = 10^9
  let a = sum [1..n `rem` 4]
  let b = sum [1 + n `rem` 4..n `rem` 2]
  let c = sum [1 + n `rem` 2..3 * n `rem` 4]
  let d = sum [1 + 3 * n `rem` 4..n]
  let total = (d + c + b + a)
  putStrLn $ "The sum is " ++ (show total)
```

Parallel code:

```
import Control.Parallel

main = do
  putStrLn "Running: "
  let n = 10^9
  let a = sum [1..n `rem` 4]
  let b = sum [1 + n `rem` 4..n `rem` 2]
  let c = sum [1 + n `rem` 2..3 * n `rem` 4]
  let d = sum [1 + 3 * n `rem` 4..n]
  let total = a `par` b `par` c `pseq` (d + c + b + a)
  putStrLn $ "The sum is " ++ (show total)
```

(Only changes are the import and `let total = ...`)

The single-core one takes `40.730s`. Parallel one is run with `-N4` and takes `38.549s`. It doesn't seem that all 4 sums are running in parallel as intended, though the summary says 2 sparks were converted. What is really going on with the sums and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think you mean `div`, not `rem` -- all but a handful of the numbers are getting bunched up into `d`.

Comment: ``n `rem` 4`` is 3 at most, since that's the remainder. Use the quotient `quot` instead.

Comment: Thanks @luqui and @chi, `quot` is what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was noted by others, you aren't actually splitting up your list evenly with `rem`.  Your lists `a`, `b`, and `c` are all empty, and `d` is the entire list.

A fixed version:

```
import Control.Parallel

main = do
  putStrLn "Running: "
  let n = 10^9
      n1 = n `quot` 4
      n2 = 2*n1
      n3 = 3*n1

  let a = sum [1..n1]
      b = sum [n1+1..n2]
      c = sum [n2+1..n3]
      d = sum [n3..n]

  let total = a `par` b `par` c `pseq` (d + c + b + a)
  putStrLn $ "The sum is " ++ (show total)
```

performs better.  I see a speed up of about two times, from 15sec for the single-threaded version to 8sec for the threaded version and `+RTS -N`.

However, there's a bug in your `total`.  This sparks computations for `a` and `b`, then fully evaluates `c` before starting to evaluate `d`.  The effect is that `a`, `b`, and `c` are run in parallel, and then `d` is run serially, so you only get a 2x speed-up.

If I replace `total` with the corrected:

```
let total = a `par` b `par` c `par` d `pseq` a + b + c + d
```

which sparks all four computations in parallel, then I see a speed-up of about 4 times to 4sec, so almost perfect parallelism on my four-core desktop.

Comment: Works perfectly! So `rem` was the main culprit. In the modified `total`, will `d` be run in its own thread? Or will the runtime know that it can be evaluated in the main thread? If only I could get ThreadScope working on Windows, it'd save me from a lot of trouble. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Short answer: `d` is run in an existing thread.  Longer answer: From a performance standpoint, it doesn't matter.  The mapping of sparks to Haskell threads to O/S threads is complicated, but it's handled by the runtime in what is generally a very efficient matter.  Creating Haskell threads is *extremely* cheap and creating sparks is even cheaper.